# Initialize Dictionary<T,T> "on the fly"

Tags: c#

I have the following classes

```cs
public class PLCWrapper
{
    public int plc_id { get; set; }
    public List<SchakelingWrapper> schakelingWrapperList { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> globalVarDict { get; set; }
}

public class SchakelingWrapper
{
    public int schakeling_id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> varDict { get; set; }
}
```

I wanna do something like below, but cann't get it fixed. Sure somebody knows how?

```cs
if (plcWrapper.schakelingWrapperList.Exists(item => item.schakeling_id == id)) {
    plcWrapper.schakelingWrapperList.Single(item => item.schakeling_id == id).varDict.Add(varName, varValue);
} else {
    plcWrapper.schakelingWrapperList.Add(new SchakelingWrapper()
    {
        schakeling_id = id,
        varDict = new Dictionary<string, string>(varName, varValue)//This does not work
    });
}
```

Comment: To initialize a dictionary with values you use the `{ }` array initialization notation like: `new Dictionary<string, string> { {varName, varValue} };`

Comment: Thank you, that worked fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line from

```
varDict = new Dictionary<string, string>(varName, varValue)//This does not work
```

to

```
varDict = new Dictionary<string, string>() {{varName, varValue}}
```

Answer (score 3):

It needs to be something like...

```
varDict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {varname, varvalue}
}
```

Comment: D'oh @Diamong GeezeR beat me to it :-)